# Unsupported framework error creating .net Class library

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

Just adding a new Class Library (.net Core ) project to my solution generate two errors:

Error NU1002 The dependency xxx.Web.Services 1.0.0 in project xxx.Web.Services does not support framework DNX,Version=v4.5.1.

Error NU1008 "netstandard1.5" is an unsupported framework.

project.json file content:

```
{
    "version" : "1.0.0-*",

    "dependencies" : {
        "NETStandard.Library" : "1.5.0-rc2-24027"
    },

    "frameworks" : {
        "netstandard1.5" : {
            "imports" : "dnxcore50"
        }
    }
}
```

Project.lock.json file content:

```
{
    "locked" : false,
    "version" : 2,
    "targets" : {
        "DNX,Version=v4.5.1" : {
            "NETStandard.Library/1.5.0-rc2-24027" : {
                "type" : "package"
            }
        },
        "DNX,Version=v4.5.1/win7-x86" : {
            "NETStandard.Library/1.5.0-rc2-24027" : {
                "type" : "package"
            }
        },
        "DNX,Version=v4.5.1/win7-x64" : {
            "NETStandard.Library/1.5.0-rc2-24027" : {
                "type" : "package"
            }
        }
    },
    "libraries" : {
        "NETStandard.Library/1.5.0-rc2-24027" : {
            "type" : "package",
            "sha512" : "SD27bvP2gNnlpC7HZUbnPOXS1M7VbBZoi0bdlqe5tj7weJQ2EyGDGw8mi7K1yUmeqjL6jPWBLSC28TDaLnyqwA==",
            "files" : ["dotnet_library_license.txt", "NETStandard.Library.1.5.0-rc2-24027.nupkg", "NETStandard.Library.1.5.0-rc2-24027.nupkg.sha512", "NETStandard.Library.nuspec", "ThirdPartyNotices.txt"]
        }
    },
    "projectFileDependencyGroups" : {
        "" : ["NETStandard.Library >= 1.5.0-rc2-24027"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change version in global.json (Solution items).

example:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview1-002702"
  }
}
```

also, probably need to change

```
 \DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props –> \DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props

\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.targets –> \DotNet.Web\Microsoft.DotNet.Web.targets
```

in your xproj file.

Best solution (not project), would be to create brand new solution and see how it's all done there.

Comment: I recreated the projects within the same solution, which left me with the old `project.json` file. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install .NET Core RC2 Tools for Visual Studio 2015 in order to use RC2.

You can find Instructions on the [Microsoft .NET Core Website](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core).

Comment: Thanks! I do it, but the error still happening, and also appear one more error: 
The design time host build failed with the following error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object xxx.Web.Services 

When i click the error, it takes me to the file Microsoft.DotNet.Commons.Target:
    <DesignTimeHostBuild
      Condition="'$(_DesignTimeHostBuild)' == 'true'"
      Port="$(DTHPort)"
      HostID="$(DTHHostID)"
      ContextID="$(DTHContextID)"
      DTHProtocolVersion="$(DTHProtocolVersion)"
      Rebuild ="$(RebuildInvoked)"
    />